# MySQL - How to get sum of duplicates' adjacent fields

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sum

I want to get the total points for each pizza. So, for example, Caramelized Onion should have 12 points, and Breakfast should have five.

SQLFIDDLE [link here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf32/1/0) Here is the MySQL query:

```
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.first_pick_points as points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.first_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.second_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.second_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.third_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.third_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.fourth_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.fourth_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.fifth_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.fifth_pick = pizza_table.id
```

These are the current results:

```
NAME                POINTS
Caramelized Onion   5
Buffalo Wing        5
Caramelized Onion   5
BM²                 4
asdf                4
Chaco               4
Breakfast           3
Chaco               3
Cheese Bread        3
The Karlyn          2
Caramelized Onion   2
Chicken Bacon Ranch 2
Buffalo Wing        1
Breakfast           1
Breakfast           1
```

This is what I would like returned:

```
NAME                POINTS
Caramelized Onion   12
Chaco               7
Buffalo Wing        6
Breakfast           5
BM²                 4
asdf                4
Cheese Bread        3
The Karlyn          2
Chicken Bacon Ranch 2
```

How do I achieve the results I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an aggregate but it also appears that you will need to change your query to use `UNION ALL` between each query:

```
select name, sum(points) Total
from
(
  SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.first_pick_points as points
  FROM results_table
  INNER JOIN pizza_table
    ON results_table.first_pick = pizza_table.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.second_pick_points
  FROM results_table
  INNER JOIN pizza_table
    ON results_table.second_pick = pizza_table.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.third_pick_points
  FROM results_table
  INNER JOIN pizza_table
    ON results_table.third_pick = pizza_table.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.fourth_pick_points
  FROM results_table
  INNER JOIN pizza_table
    ON results_table.fourth_pick = pizza_table.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.fifth_pick_points
  FROM results_table
  INNER JOIN pizza_table
    ON results_table.fifth_pick = pizza_table.id
) d
group by name
order by total desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/882e3/155).

Note, I also adjusted your query to use ANSI JOIN syntax (`INNER JOIN`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and link to SQLFiddle.

Comment: @bdd85 You are welcome, you were very close with your current query! :)

Answer (score 0):

// A simple group by should do what you want:

```
SELECT name, SUM(points) AS points
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: The question seems to be completely different than what I answered for in the first place...

Comment: Agreed.  Downvote is ridiculous.  I'm upvoting to encourage the good answer to the question as it was originally presented.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UNION ALL` along with a `Group by` clause at the end - Also added the use of `SUM`

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/882e3/156

```
Select name, SUM(points) From(
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.first_pick_points as points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.first_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION ALL
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.second_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.second_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION ALL
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.third_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.third_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION All
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.fourth_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.fourth_pick = pizza_table.id
UNION All
SELECT pizza_table.name, results_table.fifth_pick_points
FROM results_table, pizza_table
WHERE results_table.fifth_pick = pizza_table.id) x
Group by name
```